# unexpected line 1 syntaxError:

Tags: python

I've got an error I cant figure out, the code is:

```
def distance_from_zero(6):
    if type(6) == int or type(6) == float:
        return abs(6):
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
File "python", line 1
def distance_from_zero(6):
                       ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I cant figure out why ('number'): would be wrong,
It's probably something simple but any help would be great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 6 is an integer literal so can't be used as a parameter to functions. You should replace it with sth like a name *number*: `distance_from_zero(number): ...`

Comment: Also you have colon in `return abs(6):` which needs to be removed

Comment: The change from `6` to `number` should be throughout the function, not just in the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Name the argument, not a specific number.

```
def distance_from_zero(num):
    if type(num) == int or type(num) == float:
        return abs(num)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```